# Express JS Websocket Connection to wss failed without error but still able to communicate

Tags: express, websocket

I am using an Express JS to initiate websocket connection. Below is the following configuration that I used.

socket.js

```
const ip_address = `${process.env.MIX_HTTPS_APP_URL}`;
const socket_port = `${process.env.MIX_EXPRESS_PORT}`;
const URL = ip_address + ":" + socket_port;
export const socket = io(URL, { autoConnect: true });
socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {
    // console.log(event, args);
});
```

index.js

```
const app = express();
// app settings
/** Create HTTP server. */
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(env.privateKey, "utf8");
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(env.certificate, "utf8");
const options = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
};

const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);

/** Create socket connection */
const socketio = new Server(server);
global.io = socketio.listen(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: env.url,
  },
});

global.io.on("connection", WebSockets.connection);

/** Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces. */
/** Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event. */
server.on("listening", () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port:: ${env.url}:${port}/`);
});
```

Though I can emit and listen to socket, I am still getting this error message. How should I solve this so that users wont see this error message when they view the console?

[image: Console Log]

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your example, the listening on port should be on http server, & socket.io should just attach to on new conn.

see doc https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/#with-an-https-server

Hope this helps.

Comment: but the listen on port is already attached to server